# How can I get http response body when request is failed in java?

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I'm looking for a way to receive the response body when a request ends up with the status 400.
I'm now using java.net to make http connection.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
InputStream response = new URL("http://localhost:8888/login?token=token").openStream();
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response)) {
    String responseBody = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    System.out.println(responseBody);
}
```

Right now, I end up with this error

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL

When I open the url in my browser it shows me a json file representing what went wrong, but now, I can't receive that response in java.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I open the url in my browser it shows me a json file representing what went wrong, but now, I can't receive that response in java."? Are you able to see the response in the browser of this given URL and not able to get in your java code?

Comment: @AmitVyas yes, I get code 400 in browser as well, but it doesn't stop me from getting the response. In java, on the other hand, it raises an exception and I can't get the response.

Comment: You need ot use  HttpUrlConenction. Sample :  URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8888/login?token=token");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());

Comment: Race condition we reached to same answer same time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code :

```
package com.abc.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String url = "http://localhost:8888/login?token=token";
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            InputStream inputStream;
            if (200 <= responseCode && responseCode <= 299) {
                inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            } else {
                inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
            }

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String currentLine;

            while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                response.append(currentLine);

            System.out.println(response.toString());
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually the error is in the first line, when I'm getting response input stream.

Comment: @ArmanBabaei : Try the added code in your java class and see what response object you are getting via JSON.

Comment: first, I can't get (InputStream response). second, InputStream doesn't seem to have the method errorBody.

Comment: @ArmanBabaei : Replaced the code with complete lines. Try this if u can.

Comment: @ArmanBabaei : Thanks buddy ! yeah saw your approach... yes this is how we can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach and now it works.

```
URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:8888/login?token=token");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);

System.out.println("Status Code : " + con.getResponseMessage());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
con.getErrorStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
System.out.println("Response Body:");
System.out.println(response.toString());
```